# Getting an 'undefined method' error when trying to generate simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just trying to get some practice in with rails and have started my first project. I am creating a simple project where personal trainers can register profiles and look for work at gyms.
However when trying to navigate to the new personal trainer page this error pops up:

```
undefined method `pts_path' for #<#<Class:0x5d14ef8>:0x5690b68>
```

My personal trainer controller looks like this:

```
class PersonaltrainersController < ApplicationController


     def index
          @PT = Pt.all
      end

      def new
          @PT = Pt.new
      end

      def show
      end


      def create
      end

      def contact
      end

      def edit
      end
    end
```

Under the routes file I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :personaltrainers
 root 'personaltrainers#index'
end
```

My simple_form looks like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @PT do |form| %>
    <%= form.input :name %>
    <%= form.input :age %>
    <%= form.input :sex %>
    <%= form.input :experience %>
<% end %>

personaltrainers_path   GET /personaltrainers(.:format) personaltrainers#index
POST    /personaltrainers(.:format) personaltrainers#create
new_personaltrainer_path    GET /personaltrainers/new(.:format) personaltrainers#new
edit_personaltrainer_path   GET /personaltrainers/:id/edit(.:format)    personaltrainers#edit
personaltrainer_path    GET /personaltrainers/:id(.:format) personaltrainers#show
PATCH   /personaltrainers/:id(.:format) personaltrainers#update
PUT /personaltrainers/:id(.:format) personaltrainers#update
DELETE  /personaltrainers/:id(.:format) personaltrainers#destroy
root_path   GET /   personaltrainers#index
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion for what it's worth.  I use Simple_Form a lot and have struggled to get it to do all that I want at times.  Well, often.  What I should have done, what was recommended to me, and what I suggest is that you start with basic Rails forms and get used to them before using Simple_Form.  It will help you to understand what it is doing and, more importantly, why it won't do what you want it to do.  In any case, feel free to post me a question if I can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form code to:

```
<%= simple_form_for @PT, url: personaltrainers_path do |form| %>
    <%= form.input :name %>
    <%= form.input :age %>
    <%= form.input :sex %>
    <%= form.input :experience %>
<% end %>
```

`undefined method pts_path'` raised when `simple_form_for` trying to make a url from the model(`pts` it is a pluralized form of the `pt` model), but your routes have another resource name `personaltrainers`. All that you need, it's pass explicit url to the form helper, in this case  it should be `personaltrainers_path` according your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

You `index` and `new` method should be:

```
def index
  @PT = Personaltrainer.all
end

def new
  @PT = Personaltrainer.new
end
```

Btw, we (ruby devs) have a convention to use small case variable names, underscore in case of more_than_one_word. We use ALL_CAPS for constants.

Comment: Hmm it's still not working, when I try that it is giving me an .uninitialized constant' error. 
Apologies I should have posted my model code with the original post: 

class Pt < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: Add your `Pt` model and `routes` too.

Comment: I added my routes. I think I may just start again, it seems, along with the errorm I have used a lot fo bad practice in the project.

Comment: Try with scaffold, since you are a beginner. `rails g scaffold PersonalTrainer name age sex experience`